# Show $(\Bbb R\setminus\{−1\},*)$ is an Abelian group, where $a*b:=ab+a+b$. Solve $3 * x * x = 15$ in that group.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I have stumbled across the following problem and cannot understand how to solve it. Especially part b. I understand that part a must show that the rules of a Abelian group must apply for it to be an Abelian group to solve the problem, I'm just unsure how to state this.

> We consider $(\Bbb R\setminus \{−1\}, *)$, where
> $a * b := ab + a + b, a, b \in \Bbb R\setminus \{−1\}$
>
> a. Show that $(\Bbb R\setminus \{−1\}, *)$ is an Abelian group.
>
> b. Solve $3 * x * x = 15$ in the Abelian group $(\Bbb R\setminus \{−1\}, *)$, where $*$ is defined above.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Once I have a firm understanding of this I will be able to solve other Abelian group problems.

Comment: You need  to check the group axioms. What's the reason for taking out -1 ?

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?  You need to find an identity element, you need to produce inverses, you need to show associativity and commutativity.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. @wuestenfux -1 was part of the problem in the textbook. Lulu I'm particularly stuck on part B. I just don't know how to go about answering it.

Comment: Well, do you know what $3^{-1}$ is?  If so then you can get an equation of the form $x*x=A$ for some known $A$.  That's just a quadratic equation.  Or, just compute $3*(x*x)$ directly and get a quadratic equation that way.

Comment: I'm unsure where you are getting 3^−1 from. My understanding of \\ is that the set excludes -1 and the operation defined by *. Is that correct?

Comment: Use dollar signs and latex-style code to produce formatted mathematics. For instance, `$3^{-1}$` produces $3^{-1}$. The set excludes indeed $-1$, but @lulu meant by $3^{-1}$ the *inverse of $3$* with respect to the operation $*$, that is: The unique element in $a ∈ A$ with $a*3 = e = 3*a$ with $e$ being the neutral element with respect to $*$.

Comment: @Bradley But maybe include in your question a proof that $ℝ \setminus \{-1\}$ indeed becomes an abelian group with respect to $*$. What is the neutral element? What are the inverses?

Comment: As @k.stm correctly remarks, I meant the multiplicative inverse of $3$ in that group.  But you don't need to go that route...you can just write $3*x*x$ our explicitly, it's not difficult.

Comment: (@lulu Or could just try to solve $f(3*x*x) = f(15)$ instead, as I hinted at …)

Comment: @k.stm  absolutely.  And, algebraically, that's certainly the right way to do this...but I suspect that the OP needs some practice doing computations inside a group.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help people. I believe this may be obvious to you guys, however, this is my first time encountering groups. So I'm a little bit confused on what the answer should actually look like. This question has appeared in a linear algebra section of the textbook.

Comment: Like I say, just write it all out.  What is $x*x$?

Comment: @lulu so would this be what I am trying to solve? 6ab +2a + 2b = 15 ?

Comment: Neither $a$ nor $b$ appear in the equation $3*x*x=15$.  There is no reason to introduce new variables.  You have an explicit operator $*$.  What is $x*x$?

Comment: I substituted  x*x for a∗b:=ab+a+b. This is what I'm confused about

Comment: $x*x=x^2+2x$.  Can you solve it now?  Note:  I have to run out and will not be able to respond for a couple of hours.  Sorry about that.

Comment: x = -3 or 1? :O

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = \mathbb{R} \backslash \{-1\}$, and $a,b,c\in A$.

For part (a), we need to check the group axioms:

Closure: Supposing to the contrary that $-1 = a*b=ab+a+b$, then $0=ab+a+b+1=(a+1)(b+1)$, or either $a=-1$ or $b=-1$ (so $A$ is closed).

Association: $(a*b)*c = (ab+a+b)*c = (ab+a+b)c+ab+a+b+c = abc+ac+bc+ab+a+b+c = abc+ab+ac+a+b+c = a(bc+b+c)+a+(bc+b+c) = a*(bc+b+c) = a*(b*c)$ (which follows because standard addition and multiplication of reals is associative).

Identity: $a*0 = a0 + a + 0 = 0 + a + 0 = a$

Inverse: $a*(\frac{-a}{1+a}) = a\frac{-a}{1+a} + a + \frac{-a}{1+a} = \frac{-a^2}{1+a} + \frac{a^2+a}{1+a} + \frac{-a}{1+a}=0$

Commutativity follows due to the commutativity of addition and multiplication of reals: $a*b = ab+a+b = ba+b+a = b*a$.

To solve part (b), we've shown that $(A,*)$ is an Abelian group, so it doesn't matter what grouping we use to evaluate $3*x*x$ (as $*$ is associative).

Then $3*x*x = 3*(x*x) = 3*(xx+x+x) = 3*(x^2+2x)=3(x^2+2x)+3+x^2+2x$

And now it's a polynomial: $4x^2+8x+3 = 15$, or $4x^2+8x-12 = 0$
which has roots at $x = -3$ and $x = 1$.

Comment: My answer is pretty much the same! (+1)

Comment: Thank you greatly for this answer. I now understand what is going on. The only part i'm not too sure about is ab+a+b+1=(a+1)(b+1) what technique was used here to get this? Sorry if this is painfully obvious.

Comment: The goal with the 'closure' section is to show that any two elements $a,b\in A = \mathbb{R}\backslash\{-1\}$ will map back to $A$. I show this by showing that if there are any $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ that map to -1, one of the two elements must be -1. I manipulated $ab+a+b=-1$ until it came to some form that gave me information about what $a$ or $b$ must be, here $(a+1)(b+1)=0$. Specifically, I noticed that you could factor the four term expression $ab+a+b+1$ into two binomials: $(a+1)(b+1)$.

Comment: Thank you so much! One last question, following your method and @lulu I got to the answer of x for part b, being -3 and 1. However, the answer posted above by Shaun is different? Is there a reason for this.

Comment: The values of $x$ are the same, @Bradley; work it out! For example, $$-1-2=-3.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Let $A = ℝ\setminus\{-1\}$ and $f\colon A → ℝ^×,~x ↦ x + 1$. For $a, b ∈ A$, compare $f(a)·f(b)$ with $a*b$.

Answer (score 1):

For **closure**, with $a,b\in\Bbb R\setminus \{-1\}$, we have $a*b=ab+a+b\in\Bbb R$; but suppose $ab+a+b=-1$: then $a(b+1)+(b+1)=0$, *i.e.*, $(a+1)(b+1)=0$, which is impossible since neither $a$ nor $b$ is $-1$.

For **associativity**, let $a,b,c\in \Bbb R\setminus\{-1\}$ and proceed like so:

$$\begin{align}
(a*b)*c&=(ab+a+b)*c\\
&=(ab+a+b)c+(ab+a+b)+c\\
&=abc+ac+bc+ab+a+b+c\\
&=a(bc+b+c)+a+(bc+b+c)\\
&=a*(bc+b+c)\\
&=a*(b*c).
\end{align}$$

**Commutativity** follows from that of multiplication and addition. Observe: for any $a,b\in\Bbb R\setminus\{-1\}$, we get

$$\begin{align}
a*b&=ab+a+b\\
&=ba+b+a\\
&=b*a.
\end{align}$$

The **identity** is $0\in\Bbb R\setminus\{-1\}$. Indeed, for any $a\in\Bbb R\setminus\{-1\}$, we have

$$a*0=a(0)+a+0=a,$$

and, by commutativity, $0*a=0$ also.

The **inverse** $a'$ of an arbitrary $a\in\Bbb R\setminus\{-1\}$ with respect to $*$ is computed like so:

$$0=a*a'=aa'+a+a'$$

implies, by solving for $a'$,

$$a'=\frac{-a}{a+1};$$

to check:

$$\begin{align}
a*\left(\frac{-a}{a+1}\right)&=a\frac{-a}{a+1}+a+\frac{-a}{a+1}\\
&=\frac{-a^2+a(a+1)-a}{a+1}\\
&=0.
\end{align}$$

Hence $(\Bbb R\setminus \{-1\},*)$ is an Abelian group.

---

To solve

$$3*x*x=15,\tag{1}$$

multiply on the left of $(1)$ by the inverse $\frac{-3}{3+1}=-\frac{3}{4}$ of $3$, like this:

$$\begin{align}
x*x&=\left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)*15\\
&=\left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)\times 15 + \left(-\frac{3}{4}\right) +15\\
&=\frac{-45-3+60}{4}\\
&=3,
\end{align}$$

which gives

$$x^2+2x-3=0,$$

which has solutions

$$\begin{align}
x&=\frac{-2\pm\sqrt{2^2-4(1)(-3)}}{2(1)}\\
&=\frac{-2\pm 4}{2}\\
&=-1\pm 2.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you ever so much for this incredibly detailed response! I certainly understand part b now and I understand all of part a now apart from closure. Particularly, ab+a+b=−1: then a(b+1)+(b+1)=0, i.e., (a+1)(b+1)=0. My understanding of moving ab+a+b=−1 , to me becomes ab + a + b + 1 = 0. How did you get (a+1) (b+1) = 0?

Comment: You're welcome, @Bradley. Just reverse-engineer it: $$\begin{align} (a+1)(b+1)&=a(b+1)+(b+1)\quad\text{(distributivity)}\\ &=ab+a+b+1.\end{align}$$ You expand the brackets.